# Access columns from two different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using rails 4.2.
I have a model `User` and `Comment`

```
class User
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User has a column `name` and comment has a column `user_id` and `content`
Now i want to fetch the columns `comment.content` and `user.name`
By using join i can do like this

```
Comment.joins(:user).select(:name,:content)
```

Can you suggest an efficient method to perform the action?

Comment: did you try `User.find(1).comments`

Comment: My requirement is different. I have set of comments i want to find user corresponding to each comments and display it

Comment: okey try this `Comment.find(1).user` it will user object

Comment: i just don't have just one comment i have more

Comment: You want to list comment with username ?

Comment: yes. I want to list comment with username

Comment: did you got list of  comment object in view

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: No, i didn't find solution

Comment: you do this for displaying in view? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can namespace the columns like following:

```
Comment.joins(:user).pluck('users.name', 'comments.content')

# though, you don't need `comments.content`; `content` will work as well.
```

Comment: Comment.joins(:user).select(:name,:content) this is working fine. It list comments with username

Comment: I want an efficient method. I don't want to use join just to access one column of user and also user_id column present in comment